# An easy way to support tags in a jekyll blog

Tags: ruby, tags, tagging, liquid, jekyll

I am using the standard jekyll installation to maintain a blog, everything is going fine. Except I would really like to tag my posts.

I *can* tag a post using the YAML front matter, but how do I generate pages for each tag that can will list all posts for a tag?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This gist will generate a page per category for you: https://gist.github.com/524748

It uses a Jekyll Generator plugin, plus a Page subclass.

Answer (score 81):

Here is a solution **with alphabetically sorted tags on a single page**.
It uses Liquid only, which means that it works on GitHub Pages:

```
{% capture tags %}
  {% for tag in site.tags %}
    {{ tag[0] }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign sortedtags = tags | split:' ' | sort %}

{% for tag in sortedtags %}
  <h3 id="{{ tag }}">{{ tag }}</h3>
  <ul>
  {% for post in site.tags[tag] %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

You can see it in action [here](http://christianspecht.de/tags/).

---

**EDIT:**

There's also a way to generate a separate page for each tag without plugins *(which will work on GitHub Pages)*.

I have a more detailed explanation on my blog:
[Separate pages per tag/category with Jekyll (without plugins)](http://christianspecht.de/2014/10/25/separate-pages-per-tag-category-with-jekyll-without-plugins/)

First, you need a new layout file:

#### `/_layouts/tagpage.html`:

```
---
layout: default
---

<h1>{{ page.tag }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for post in site.tags[page.tag] %}
  <li>
    {{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}: <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

With this layout file, you can add a new tag page by adding a new file with just two lines of YAML front-matter.

Here's an example for the `jekyll` tag:

#### `/tags/jekyll/index.html`:

```
---
layout: tagpage
tag: jekyll
---
```

The only disadvantage of this approach: each time you use a new tag for the first time, you have to remember to create a new two-line file for it.

To generate the root index file *(i.e. the list of tags that links to `/tags/jekyll/index.html` etc.)*, you can use a similar solution like the one on top of this answer where I generate a single page with alphebetically sorted tags:

```
{% capture tags %}
  {% for tag in site.tags %}
    {{ tag[0] }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign sortedtags = tags | split:' ' | sort %}
{% for tag in sortedtags %}
    <a href="/tags/{{ tag }}/">{{ tag }}</a><br>
{% endfor %}
```

This will generate a list of links like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/tags/.net/">.net</a></li>
    <li><a href="/tags/authentication/">authentication</a></li>
    <li><a href="/tags/backup/">backup</a></li>
</ul>
```

*Note that this solution uses a blank to split tags, so it doesn't work when your tags contain blanks and [Yevgeniy Brikman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408824/an-easy-way-to-support-tags-in-a-jekyll-blog/21002505?noredirect=1#comment47505603_21002505) applies here as well.*

Comment: its like grabbing the information and then assigning it to a var, thanks for the post.  i'm not sure what i'll do, maybe nothing.

Comment: This is a clever hack! One issue I had is that my tags had spaces in them, so the `split: ' '` would split one tag into many words. To work around it, I used a `|` character as a delimiter instead of spaces and split on that: https://gist.github.com/brikis98/e71d6c736158080968f5

Comment: But then what does your index.html in root look like? Does it just list all of the tags/categories as links so when you click them it takes you to the tags/jekyll/index.html page?

Comment: @Jwan622: I just edited the answer and added example code for how to do this.

Comment: If you run into capitalization messing with the `sort`, you can use  `sort_natural` instead. I also ran into the tags having newlines and whitespaces (even though they don't in their front matter) so I had to pass to strip_newlines and strip like so:
`{% assign sortedtags = tags | strip_newlines | split: '|' | sort_natural %}
{% for tag in sortedtags %}
  {% assign strippedtag = tag | strip %}
  <h3 id="{{ strippedtag }}">{{ strippedtag }}</h3>
`

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around creating my new website in Jekyll or Hugo and using Bootstrap 5 or not. Your answer above here I have tons like them and want to convert all my answers into blog posts on my new website. Extracting all my stack exchange answers accepted or with 2 or more votes is easy. Converting to blog post and which technology to use for website is not so easy. Do  you have an answer posted here or a blog post about doing that?

Comment: I've written a `pre-push` hook to [detect missing tag pages](https://moments.putnamhill.net/2023/02/22/jekyll-on-personal-site/) and a bash script, `gentag`, to make tag pages. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [sites using jekyll](http://wiki.github.com/mojombo/jekyll/sites). There are a few custom forks which have implemented tagging functionality, hopefully also in the way you want :-)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question, and stumbled upon this: http://gist.github.com/143571.

It's a rake task which generates a tag list. I modified it slightly, and my version is at: 
http://github.com/mattfoster/mattfoster.github.com/blob/master/Rakefile.

Whilst this doesn't give you a page per tag, you can use anchors, which is half way there!

Comment: You can generate a list of tags without a Rake task, just using Liquid. Check out my [tags page](https://github.com/edrex/edrex.github.io/blob/master/pages/tags.html) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I use the great [Jekyll Tagging](https://github.com/pattex/jekyll-tagging) plugin that automatically generates a tags cloud and tag pages. Easy to install and use.

Here is [a page for the "photo" tag](http://nicolas-hoizey.com/tags/photo.html) on my blog (in french), and you can see the tags cloud in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Christian's answer above I made a bash script that does what he described.

https://github.com/ObjectiveTruth/objectivetruth.github.io/blob/master/rebuild_tags.sh

<s>Be sure to have the accompanying 14 line [vim script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ObjectiveTruth/objectivetruth.github.io/master/non_website_resources/create_list_of_tags.vim) in the `/non_website_resources/` directory</s>

AND

Make the `/_layouts/tagpage.html` shown in Christian's answer above but rename it to `/_layouts/tag_pages.html`

File structure should be like this:

```
.jekyll_website_root
├── _posts
├── _layout
│   ├── tag_pages.html
├── rebuild_tags.sh
```

Run from the root directory `./rebuild_tags.sh`

If you get permission denied error be sure to run `chmod 777 rebuild_tags.sh`

---

If you look at scripts comments its fairly simple:

- Uses `sed` to find all the tags in every `.md` file in `_post` directory
- Uses `sed` to massage the data to proper format
- Takes all the unique tags and makes a directory and a `index.html` for each

This way, if you have any new tags, just run the script to rebuild the pages before pushing to github

A nice simple non-plugin way to do tags

---

**EDIT**

Removed dependency on other files. Just need the one script!

Answer (score 0):

I do these with CSS. First lists an element and use the tag name as its id.

```html
<span id="{{ site.posts | map: 'tags' | uniq | join: '"></span><span id="' }}"></span>
```

And then lists all the post and use its tags as a value for the "tags" custom attribute.

```html
{% for post in site.posts %}
    <article class="post" tags="{% for tag in post.tags %}{{tag}}{% if forloop.last == false %}{{" "}}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">
        <h3><a href="{{post.url}}">{{post.title}}</a></h3>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

And then in CSS, hide all the posts by default, and only show posts with tags matches the url id/ hash

```css
.post {
    display: none;
}
{% for tag in site.tags %}#{{tag[0]}}:target ~ [tags~={{tag[0]}}]{% if forloop.last == false %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %} {
    display: block;
}
/*
The compiled version will look like this
#tagname:target ~ [tags~="tagname"], #tagname2:target ~ [tags~="tagname2"] {
   display: block;
}
*/
```

I made an article about this [here](https://rxxb.github.io/2020/11/post/jekyll-tag-listing).

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [`pre-push`](https://moments.putnamhill.net/2023/02/22/jekyll-on-personal-site/) hook to detect missing tag pages. It will offer to create the missing tag pages with a bash script, `gentag`. The hook will also warn if pushing a draft.

For simplicity, it assumes tags are entered as a yaml array in front matter which are collected with `yq`.

There's also a `pre-receive` hook to deploy the site on a personal webserver.