# Jekyll display posts by category

Tags: jekyll, liquid

scratching my head over this - help much appreciated.

I want to display a list of all my Jekyll posts, organised by category. I know Line 3 isn't correct but I can't figure out what it should be. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
{% for category in site.categories %}
    <h3>{{ category | first }}</h3>
    {% for post in page.categories.category %}
      {{ post.title }}<br>
    {% endfor %}            
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Got it! Needed an intermediate posts loop before listing out individual posts

```
<ul>
{% for category in site.categories %}
  <li><a name="{{ category | first }}">{{ category | first }}</a>
    <ul>
    {% for post in category.last %}
      <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I have test in my local and found the first of {{ posts }} is the category name and will be a empty line in html, so I add {% if post.url %} ahead `<li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>` to remove category line

Comment: hey, thanks for this, it works great! I have a question though (sorry, total jekyll noob) and probably would help improving your answer: do you know (if possible) how to put this code in a page that sits in /category/<name>, reads the <name> from the url and pulls the list of posts accordingly? (edit) my question dups here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958652/how-to-create-a-link-to-each-category/25979472#25979472

Answer (score 28):

fyi, if anyone wants to just list the posts in one category, this works (differs from above example as the category returns a list of posts...

```
<p>Posts in category "basic" are:</p>

<ul>
  {% for post in site.categories.basic %}
    {% if post.url %}
        <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a better answer and avoids the suggested hack that the accepted answer makes necessary.

Comment: How can I do this for a category name that contains white space such as 'foo bar'?

Answer (score 7):

Now there is an official plugin available for this. [**`jekyll-archives`**](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-archives).

In order to make use of it,

Add `jekyll-archives` to your `Gemfile` and `_config.yml` file.

add a configuration something similar to the below as per your need.

```
jekyll-archives:
  enabled: all
  layouts:
    year: archive/year
    month: archive/month
    day: archive/day
    tag: archive/tag
    category: archive/category
  permalinks:
    year: '/:year/'
    month: '/:year/:month/'
    day: '/:year/:month/:day/'
    tag: '/tags/:name/'
    category: '/category/:name/'
```

The `layouts` can make use of the following page attributes depending on the `archive type`.

- **page.type** - (Any one fo the following. `year`, `month`, `day`, `tag`, `category`)
- **page.title** - (Only available for the type tag and category. `Nil` otherwise.)
- **page.date** - (Depending on `page.type` you should parse out the date and month field )
- **page.posts** - (List of posts for this archive)

Here is a sample layout for archive based on years

```
<h1>Archive of posts from {{ page.date | date: "%Y" }}</h1>
<ul class="posts">
{% for post in page.posts %}
  <li>
    <span class="post-date">{{ post.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</span>
    <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<h5>Categories</h5>
{% for category in site.categories %}
    {% assign cat = category[0] %}
    <h6><a href="#">{{ cat }}</a></h6>
    {% for post in site.categories[cat] %}
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a> <small>{{ post.date }}</small>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't recall the exact syntax off-hand but something like the following code should retrieve the category names to allow your to retrieve posts for each category...

```
{% for category in site.categories %}

   {% assign cat_name = category[0] %}

  {% for post in site.categories.cat_name %}

       ...

  {% endfor%}

 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not working. Reads `{% for post in site.categories[cat_name] %}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that uses sorting (useful!):

```
{% comment %}
#
#  Change date order by adding '| reversed'
#  To sort by title or other variables use {% assign sorted_posts = category[1] | sort: 'title' %}
#
{% endcomment %}
{% assign sorted_cats = site.categories | sort %}
{% for category in sorted_cats %}
{% assign sorted_posts = category[1] | reversed %}
<h2 id="{{category[0] | uri_escape | downcase }}">{{category[0] | capitalize}}</H2>
<ul>
  {% for post in sorted_posts %}
    <li><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}{{  post.url }}">{{  post.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

This is not mine, it's taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/Phlow/57eb457898e4ac4c4a20).