# Jekyll display collection by category

Tags: jekyll

I'm having trouble figuring out how to sort the content of a collection by category. I've found a very similar question on how to sort posts by category but it doesn't seem to work with collections [Jekyll display posts by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872861/jekyll-display-posts-by-category).

Let's say I have a collection called 'cars' with two categories: 'old' and 'new'. How can I display only cars with the category 'old'?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can sort, group or filter collection like any other object like page or posts.

**_my_collection/mustang.md**

```
---
category: 'old'
abbrev: tang
---
mustang content
```

**_my_collection/corvette.md**

```
---
category: 'new'
abbrev: vet
---
corvette content
```

#### Filtering

```
{% assign newcars = site.my_collection | where: "category", "new" %}
```

#### Sorting

```
{% assign allcarssorted = site.my_collection | sort: "category" %}
```

#### Grouping

```
{% assign groups = site.my_collection | group_by: "category" | sort: "name" %}
```

This groups your cars and then sort groups by name that is the category.

```
{% for group in groups %}
    {{ group.name }}
    {% for item in group.items %}
        {{item.abbrev}}
    {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Can you ask a real question, explaining what you're trying to do ?

Comment: A collection of tutorials, organized like a tree (topic, subtopic, sub-subtopic, etc). I created folders to reflect that but I'm wondering how to access the structure like in a menu, or in a list of child topics...

Comment: Not a question in a comment. A real question on SO.

Comment: Oh right sure I'm still exploring Jelyll. Will probably post later.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274603/jekyll-linked-documents-in-collections

Comment: You can also have other taxonomy names, not just "category" .  For example `country: Romania`, and then filter using `where: 'country', 'Romania'`