# How to sort collection directory by category?

Tags: jekyll

**Note:** I have already tried to solve this by looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100220/jekyll-display-collection-by-category) issue.

What is my problem?
 I am trying to create a website with Jekyll that will represent my CV. I created multiple folders so that I can constantly update my resume without having to change my index.html all the time. That's what they look like:
[image]
My *_education,_experience,_interests* all work fine. However I want to make something different for _skills.
I want to fill them with different directories such as Proffesional, Coding, Software... And in those files there will be markdown files. These markdown files will include
`---
categories: professional
---`

And then my index.html file will contain a loop:

```
<ul> {% for category in site.skills.categories%}
     <li><ul>{% for item in site.skills.[category] %}
               <li> {{item.title}} </li>
             {% endfor %}
     </ul>
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This however, does not work if I modify my markdown files in skills with categories in front matter. Probably I am missing the syntax.
This is how my page would look like. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said that I tried the issue that I linked and it didn't work, what I really did was... a typo. It works now. My answer was:

```
            {% assign groups = site.skills | group_by: "category" | sort: "name" %}
            {% for group in groups %}

                      <!-- Subtitle -->
                      <h3 class="section-item-title-1">{{group.name}} Skills</h3>
                      <!-- /Subtitle -->

                      <!-- content -->
                      <ul class="skills-list">
                          <!-- item-list -->

                          {%for item in group.items%}

                          <li>
                          <div class="progress">

                            <span class="progress-type">{{item.title}}</span>

                          </div>
                          </li>

                          {% endfor %}
                      </ul>

              {% endfor %}
```

I am sorry if there was an ugly code block. I am not that experenced yet.