# how to list my posts in a sub directory of _posts order by time with jekyll

Tags: html, yaml, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I'm using [mmistakes/minimal-mistakes](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes) which is build with jekyll to build my github pages.

I want to list all of my posts under `_posts/android` in `_pages/android.html`. Meaning, I want to put `2016-09-01-aaa.md`,`2016-09-02-bbb.md` and `2016-08-26-ccc.md` but not `2016-09-03-ddd.md` in `_pages/android.html`.

Here is my project's directory structure:

```
.
├── _config.yml
├── _pages
│    └── android.html
├── _posts
│    ├── android
│    │    ├── third-party
│    │    │    ├── 2016-09-01-aaa.md
│    │    │    └── 2016-09-02-bbb.md
│    │    └── handler
│    │         └── 2016-08-26-ccc.md
│    └── java
│         └── effective-java
│              └── 2016-09-03-ddd.md
└── _site
     ├── index.html (my github home page)
     ├── android
     │    ├── index.html (generated from "_pages/android.html")
     │    ├── third-party
     │    │    ├── aaa
     │    │    │    └── index.html
     │    │    └── bbb
     │    │         └── index.html
     │    └── handler
     │         └── ccc
     │              └── index.html
     └── java
          └── effective-java
               └── ddd
                    └── index.html
```

Here is `_pages/android.html`:

(But it will list all the posts under `_posts` ,
How can I make it list posts under `_posts/android` only ?)

```
---
layout: archive
permalink: /android/
excerpt: "android"
author_profile: false
sidebar:
  nav: "android"
---
{% include base_path %}

<h3 class="archive__subtitle">{{ site.data.ui-text[site.locale].recent_posts | default: "Recent Posts" }}</h3>

{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% include archive-single.html %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is `_include/base_path`:

```
{% if site.url %}
  {% assign base_path = site.url | append: site.baseurl %}
{% else %}
  {% assign base_path = site.github.url %}
{% endif %}
```

Here is `2016-09-01-aaa.md`:
(Other posts is similar to this.)

```
---
title: aaa
categories: /android/third-party/
---
write some contents.
```

Here is the snippet of `_config.yml`:

```
# Site Settings
locale                   : "zh-CN"
title                    : "IT Tech"
title_separator          : "-"
name                     : "TesTName"
description              : "Android Java HTML CSS JavaScript Ubuntu"
url                      : "http://localhost:4000"  # the base hostname & protocol for your site e.g. "https://mmistakes.github.io"
baseurl                  : # the subpath of your site, e.g. "/blog"

# Defaults
defaults:
  # _posts
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: posts
    values:
      layout: single
      author_profile: true
      read_time: false
      comments: true
      share: true
      related: false
  # _pages
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: pages
    values:
      layout: single
      author_profile: true
      related: true
```

So, how can I make it ? I'm really not good at the html and jekyll things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34344690/6612932), the following should work:

```
{% for post in site.categories.android %}
  {% include archive-single.html %}
{% endfor %}
```

With categories declared like this:

```
categories: android third-party
```

Comment: I have tried, `{% for post in site.categories.android %}` doesn't works , neither of `{% for post in site.posts.android %}` .    Those code shows nothing.

Comment: @gncavalry I think the problem is your category declaration. Instead of `categories: /android/third-party/`, try `categories: android third-party`

Comment: You are right , change the categories to `android third-party` and use the code{% for post in site.categories.android %}
  {% include archive-single.html %}
{% endfor %}.  There must be someting wrong when I verified the first time.  Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

The `post.path` will list all your posts in subfolder `_posts/android`

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.path contains 'android' %}
     {% include archive-single.html %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```