# How can I have a .htaccess-tag with Jekyll?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, jekyll

Jekyll creates folders for every part of the url. So when I have:

```
www.myurl.com/blog/tag/.htaccess
```

it (this [_tag_gen.rb](http://charliepark.org/tags-in-jekyll/) plugin) actually creates:

```
www.myurl.com 
            └─ blog
               └─ tag
                  └──.htaccess
                     └── index.html
```

This is a problem, because of Apache `.htaccess` files. When I have this folder, the whole `tag`-folder becomes inaccessible.

But as it works for Wordpress ([proof](http://martin-thoma.com/tag/.htaccess/) - but, I think, WP does not actually generate the folder) I think this should also work with Jekyll.

How can I have a `.htaccess` tag with Jekyll that doesn't mess everything else up?

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely *need* to create your tags this way, i.e. with a plugin that generates an actual folder for each tag?

If you can live with that, you could use [a single page containing **all** tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002505/6884) instead...your problem would just go away then.