# How do you sort site.tags by post count in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Apologies as I'm new to Ruby, but I'm trying to add a liquid tag to my template that I can loop over to show a list of the five most popular tags.

For some reason this plugin just outputs a single tag when I use it.

Here is what I put in mu plugin:

```
module Jekyll
  class PopularTags < Liquid::Tag

    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
    end

    def render(context)
      tags = context.registers[:site].tags
      return tags.sort_by { |tag, posts| posts.count }
    end
  end
end
Liquid::Template.register_tag('popular_tags', Jekyll::PopularTags)
```

Here is what I put in my template:

```
{% popular_tags %}
```

Comment: Try to inspect what `popular_tags` returns, also calling `super` on initialize without arguments smells bad.

Comment: When it leaves the ruby method it is sorted correctly.

Comment: OK, I'm making progress. Now I can't seem to loop the tag in a for loop, but if I just dump it out in Liquid, it's all there, sorted.

Comment: check this, http://blog.lanyonm.org/articles/2013/11/21/alphabetize-jekyll-page-tags-pure-liquid.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well actually, from what I'm currently reading, the Tag plugins in Jekyll should be used just like a tag and not like a variable. So in that case, you should indeed use this in your template :

```
{% popular_tags %}
```

But it's the behaviour of your class that seems to be wrong. It should not return a variable/hash, it should return **the HTML code that will be displayed in stead of the `popular_tags` tag**.

For instance, here's something you could be doing :

```
module Jekyll
  class PopularTags < Liquid::Tag

    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
    end

    def render(context)
      tags = context.registers[:site].tags

      html = "<ul>"
      sorted = tags.sort_by { |t,posts| posts.count }
      sorted.each do |t, posts|
        html << "<li>TAG: #{t} (#{posts.count})</li>"
      end
      html << "</ul>"

      html
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('popular_tags', Jekyll::PopularTags)
```

Hope this helps. I just tried it and it's working as intended. If you want to display the most used tags first, just change the `sort_by` line, and use `-posts.count` instead of `posts.count`.

You can have a look at [this other plugin source code](https://gist.github.com/ilkka/710577), might help you.

Comment: Many thanks, this helps. I was trying to keep the markup out of the plugin and in the template, where I thought it belonged. How would one  provide a variable to the template in Jekyll then?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I'm not using Jekyll myself, just gave it a quick look to help. Maybe your ``popular_tags`` could return a serialized Array or a string in a specific format, that you could split afterward in your views, but I'm not sure this would be a really clean way to achieve this.

Answer (score 20):

It's also possible to do this without plugins, which means that it will work on [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

I'm already doing something similar *(without plugins as well)* on [my blog](http://christianspecht.de/), where I'm displaying a list of tags with post counts, alphabetically sorted. [The source code is here](https://github.com/christianspecht/blog/blob/49b67d1d86a41f00f705804f69dbae3f6ee17f9a/src/_layouts/default.html#L120).

It's not much effort to modify this so that it sorts by post count:

```
{% capture tags %}
  {% for tag in site.tags %}
    {{ tag[1].size | plus: 1000 }}#{{ tag[0] }}#{{ tag[1].size }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign sortedtags = tags | split:' ' | sort %}
{% for tag in sortedtags reversed %}
    {% assign tagitems = tag | split: '#' %}
    <li><a href="/tags/#{{ tagitems[1] }}">{{ tagitems[1] }} ({{ tagitems[2] }})</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

---

I guess there's some explanation necessary:

`tag[0]` is the name of the tag.
`tag[1]` is an array with the posts for the tag, so `tag[1].size` is the post count.

1. Basically, we would need to capture something like `tag[1].size#tag[0]`, which would result in a string like this:

   ```
   3#TagWithThreePosts 1#TagWithOnePost 2#TagWithTwoPosts
   ```
2. Then, in the `{% assign sortedtags =  ...` line, we're splitting that again and sorting it, so the result is a sorted array of strings:

   - `1#TagWithOnePost`
   - `2#TagWithTwoPosts`
   - `3#TagWithThreePosts`
3. In the final loop, we loop this in reverse (=descending) order, split by `#` to get the tag name and the post count, and display the link.

The only problems are tags with 10 and more posts.
Since we're sorting strings, the result of step 2 would look like this:

- `1#TagWithOnePost`
- `10#TagWithTenPosts` ← **WRONG ORDER, because it's a string!**
- `2#TagWithTwoPosts`
- `3#TagWithThreePosts`

To fix this, I'm adding 1000 to the post count for the purpose of sorting. So `1#...` and `10#...` become `1001#...` and `1010#...`, and they are ordered properly.

I still want to display the actual post number *(without 1000 added)*, so I'm appending it as the third item in the `{% capture tags %}` part:

```
{{ tag[1].size | plus: 1000 }}#{{ tag[0] }}#{{ tag[1].size }}
```

---

By the way, I'm linking to a tag page (`/tags/#blah`, e.g. all posts for all tags on a single page) which I implemented in a similar fashion as well, [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002505/6884).

Comment: That's pretty cool! Is it also possible to sort the tags on post count?

Comment: This is pretty slick, but it doesn't work with tags with spaces

Comment: This is really nice but it doesn't work with tags with spaces as @mpchadwick added and it doesn't sort tags alphabetically this way. It does reverse alphabetical order due to reversing the list in between. I fixed these two issues and posted the solution on my blog here: http://www.gungorbudak.com/blog/2017/12/08/tags-cloud-sorted-by-post-count-for-jekyll-blogs-without-plugins/. This is not an accepted answer but it's really good so I'm still sharing. Thanks!

Comment: @GungorBudak, another solution is to change `plus: 1000` into `minus: 1000`.

Comment: This is very clever, and the only solution that has worked for me. I've tried writing custom Liquid filters to no avail and I don't want to install plugins. @mpchadwick: fwiw, I got around that problem by using `{{ tag[0] | slugify }}` for the sorting. You could even recover the original `tag[0]` value later by adding it as another item to the sorted tuple that gets returned.