# Sorting Jekyll tags by number of posts

Tags: ruby, sorting, jekyll

The code which displays tags for the Jekyll theme I am using is given below. It currently shows tags in alphabetical order. What should I change to sort via post count? I saw [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700749/how-do-you-sort-site-tags-by-post-count-in-jekyll/24702179) but the code they used was very different from what is in this theme.

```
{% capture site_tags %}{% for tag in site.tags %}{{ tag | first | downcase }}&#x1F;{{ tag | first }}{% unless forloop.last %}&#x1E;{% endunless %}{% endfor %}{% endcapture %}
{% assign site_tags = site_tags | split: '&#x1E;' | sort %}
{% capture site_tags %}{% for tag in site_tags %}{{ tag | split: '&#x1F;' | last }}{% unless forloop.last %}&#x1E;{% endunless %}{% endfor %}{% endcapture %}
{% assign site_tags = site_tags | split: '&#x1E;' %}

{% assign post_count = site.posts | size %}
{% capture tag_counts %}{% for tag in site_tags %}{{site.tags[tag] | size | times: 10 | plus: post_count | minus: 1 | divided_by: post_count }}{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}{% endfor %}{% endcapture %}
{% assign tag_counts = tag_counts | split: ',' %}

<ul class="tags quick-links">
{% for tag in site_tags %}
    {% assign tag_data = site.data.tags[tag] %}
    {% capture tag_classes %}tag tag-size-{{ tag_counts[forloop.index0] }} tag-{{ tag | slugify }}{% endcapture %}
    {% capture tag_name %}{% if tag_data.title %}{{ tag_data.title }}{% else %}{{ tag }}{% endif %}{% endcapture %}
    <li><a href="{{ include.baseurl }}#{{ tag | slugify }}" class="{{ tag_classes }}">{{ tag_name }}<span class="count">{{ site.tags[tag] | size }}</span></a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The link to [the file](https://github.com/IamSreeman/iamsreeman.github.io/blob/main/_includes/tag_cloud.html). This is the [theme](https://github.com/TWiStErRob/twisterrob.github.io/blob/master/_includes/tag_cloud.html) I used.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: can you also share the generated html

Comment: @Chandan view-source:https://iamsreeman.github.io/blog/

Comment: just to confirm you want the tags as `Philosophy[2], Quantum mechanics[2],Textbook[2],Atheism[1],Ethics[1],....`

Comment: @Chandan Yes exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `{{ tag | first | downcase }}` to `{{ tag[1].size | plus: 1000 }}` for sorting with post count.

The problem left is the post will appear in ascending order which can easily solved by reversing the order by adding `reverse` after tag are sorted.

```
{% capture site_tags %}
  {% for tag in site.tags %}
    {{ tag[1].size | plus: 1000 }}&#x1F;{{ tag | first }}
    {% unless forloop.last %}&#x1E;{% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign site_tags = site_tags | split: '&#x1E;' | sort | reverse %}
```