# Jekyll plugin to handle categories doesn't work on GitHub

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I've copied the Jekyll plugin to generate Category pages using an official source (https://github.com/recurser/jekyll-plugins) into my Github repository and it doesn't work, I keep on getting a 404 page. That said if I test on my local machine both in the Jekyll server and in the _site directory it works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:
If you don't want to generate your site locally and push the created HTML files to GitHub *(like David Jacquel suggested in his answer)*, you can create **one single page with all categories**.

Check out this answer:
[**An easy way to support tags in a jekyll blog**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002505/6884)
*(Note: I'm using tags instead of categories there, but both work exactly the same way in Jekyll as far as I know. So you can just take my code and replace `site.tags` by `site.categories`)*

I admit, one page per category looks nicer, but my solution has the advantage that it works on Github Pages (because it's just vanilla Liquid, no plugin).

---

**EDIT:**

In the meantime, I wrote a blog post how to make separate pages per category *without* using a plugin:
[Separate pages per tag/category with Jekyll (without plugins)](http://christianspecht.de/2014/10/25/separate-pages-per-tag-category-with-jekyll-without-plugins/)

Comment: I've been looking for the way to handle the post categories without plug-in and it works. I'm using it for *[topic navigation](http://hyip.github.io/info/project/)* on sidebar. Thanks for sharing the code

Answer (score 2):

GitHub Pages does not support most plug-ins. They don't want anything crazy going on behind the scenes.

Here's how I do categories with Github Pages. It is not wholly automatic, as it requires a separate .html file for each category you want to set up. But it works without any plugins or wizardry on Github Pages.

Create a categoryname.html file in your root directory. For example, `hardware.html` for a Hardware category. Run a for loop on all of the site's posts and check the post.category

```html
<div class="posts">
  {% for post in site.posts %}

    {% assign author = site.authors[post.author] %}
    {{ author.display_name }}

  {% if post.category == 'Hardware' %}
  <div class="post">
    <h1 class="post-title">
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </h1>
    {{ post.content }}
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

In your posts, you would use the `YAML` header to add the category to the post. Like the code below:

```
---
layout: post
title: How We Built a Hardware Product
author: Author Name
category: Hardware
---
```

That should do it. It'll create a `/hardware/` page that will include all of your posts with the Hardware category. Make sure you're case-sensitive on your `YAML` and category names (`hardware != Hardware and category != Category`).

Answer (score 1):

[Github pages only support a small number of Jekyll plugins](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-plugins-with-github-pages/).

If you want to use your plugins, you'll have to generate your site locally and push it on github pages. If you do this, add a `.nojekyll` file at the root of your repository to tell github to not process you files.