# How can I sort posts by tags in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm not familiar with Ruby and I know there's a common Jekyll plugin for doing this but I tried all day and have not been able to get it working.

I added this plugin:

```
module Jekyll
  class TagIndex < Page
    def initialize(site, base, dir, tag)
      @site = site
      @base = base
      @dir = dir
      @name = 'index.html'
      self.process(@name)
      self.read_yaml(File.join(base, '_layouts'), 'tag_index.html')
      self.data['tag'] = tag
      tag_title_prefix = site.config['tag_title_prefix'] || 'Posts Tagged &ldquo;'
      tag_title_suffix = site.config['tag_title_suffix'] || '&rdquo;'
      self.data['title'] = "#{tag_title_prefix}#{tag}#{tag_title_suffix}"
    end
  end
  class TagGenerator < Generator
    safe true
    def generate(site)
      if site.layouts.key? 'tag_index'
        dir = site.config['tag_dir'] || 'tag/tag'
        site.tags.keys.each do |tag|
          write_tag_index(site, File.join(dir, tag), tag)
        end
      end
    end
    def write_tag_index(site, dir, tag)
      index = TagIndex.new(site, site.source, dir, tag)
      index.render(site.layouts, site.site_payload)
      index.write(site.dest)
      site.pages << index
    end
  end
end
```

and to _config.yml I added

```
tag_dir: /tag
```

I display the list of tags with this include file:

```
<div class="tags modal">
    <ul>
        {% for tag in site.tags %}
        <li>
            <a href="/tag/{{ tag | first | slugize }}/">
                {{ tag | first }}
            </a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

And when I try to select a tag, the url changes appropriately but nothing else changes.  It does not display my tag_index template or filter the tags.

[The site can be previewed and full source is available here.](https://github.com/dcondrey/dcondrey.github.io)  I've been banging my head against the wall for a while and can't for the damned of me figure out what I'm not doing right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Only some plugins are supported by github pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-plugins-with-github-pages/). Your tag pages are not currently generated.

If you want to use your tag plugin, you have to

- generate you site locally
- add an empty **.nojekyll** file
- push the generated files in you **master** branch
- you can also push you code in an other branch like **code**

Comment: Issue was actually due to the history.js code and how I was implementing it but this info was useful as well.  Thx.

Comment: Now I have the git repo based in `_sites`.  Is it possible to add the parent directory with the dev files as a branch to that?

Comment: Look my explanation on how to setup multiple branch [here](https://github.com/djacquel/JekyllVersioningWorkflows#user-content-setup-explanation)

Answer (score 5):

If one single tag page with all posts for all tags *(like [this one on my blog](http://christianspecht.de/tags/))* is enough for you, you can [just generate it with Jekyll/Liquid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002505/6884), without using any plugins at all.

If you absolutely want a separate page for each tag, then you have only two choices:

1. [David Jacquel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26324470/6884) *(generate the page with the plugin on your local machine and push only the generated HTML to GitHub)*
2. Each time you're writing a post where you use a new tag for the first time, [manually create a new page with the tag name](http://christianspecht.de/2014/10/25/separate-pages-per-tag-category-with-jekyll-without-plugins/) [where you load all posts for that tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26239671/6884)

Both choices are a bit more work than the tag page from my blog *(see the first link)*, but there's no other way when you want one page per tag on GitHub Pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't solve the trouble of sorting your `posts` by **tags**, you may consider
[collections](https://blog.webjeda.com/jekyll-collections/).

**Collections** in Jekyll is a set of items which has a certain relation between individual items but may not have a chronological arrangement.

For example, let’s consider you have a blog which is about movie reviews. You write your reviews as posts. So for every movie you create a post. Let’s say you want to make a list of **Top 25** must watch movies or **Top 10** scary movies which will have all the details of each movie.

> In this case, [`posts`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/) or [`pages`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/) are not a good choice to go with. Use [`collections`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) instead.

You can have any number of collections. It is a collection of certain kind of things. A collection of fruits, a collection of veggies, collections of beverages etc. Do not create collections for subsets, for example, say exotic fruits. They come under the fruit collection. In such cases use **categories**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe things have changed since this was posted, but sorting via tags (or categories) is built into Jekyll. You can do this by using the proposed method in [the docs on Jekyll's website](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#categories-and-tags).

From the site:

> Jekyll makes the categories available to us at `site.categories`. Iterating over `site.categories` on a page gives us another array with two items, the first item is the name of the category and the second item is an array of posts in that category... **For tags it’s exactly the same except the variable is** `site.tags`.

```
{% for tag in site.tags %}
  <h3>{{ tag[0] }}</h3>
  <ul>
    {% for post in tag[1] %}
      <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

That ☝️ will give you each tag and its associated posts of your Jekyll site. You could go a step further and only return a specific tag(s). For example only list the tag `nsfw` and its associated posts.

```
{% for tag in site.tags %}
  {%- if tag[0] == "nsfw" -%}
    <h3>{{ tag[0] }}</h3>
    <ul>
      {% for post in tag[1] %}
        <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {%- endif -%}
{% endfor %}
```