# How can I add proper tag support for jekyll blog hosted on GitHub?

Tags: github, tags, jekyll, blogs, github-pages

**Problem**

Recently I added tag support for my personal blog, but I am not happy with a way that it was done.

Blog uses [jekyll](/questions/tagged/jekyll) with [github-pages](/questions/tagged/github-pages), so my solution has many limitations that platform comes with.

In order to create tag **javascript** I created file `tag/javascript/index.html` with following content:

```
---
layout: tag
tag: javascript
---
```

And it in my **tag** layout file I have following code:

```
---
layout: default
---
<div class="tag-header">
    posts related to <strong>{{ page.tag }}</strong>
</div>
{% for post in site.posts %}
{% if post.tags contains page.tag %}
<section class="post">
    <header>
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </header>
    <time>
        {{ post.date | date_to_string }}
    </time>
    <summary>
        {% if post.excerpt %}
        {{ post.excerpt }}
        <a href="{{ post.url }}">read more</a>
        {% endif %}
    </summary>
    <div class="tags">
        {% for tag in post.tags %}
        <span>
            <a href="/tag/{{ tag }}">#{{ tag }}</a>
        </span>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</section>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Result is something like this [posts related to **javascript**](http://gevorg.me/tag/javascript/).

**Question**

How can I automate tag creation process, so it does not require manual **tag** file creation (`tag/javascript/index.html` from sample)?

**Notice**

I have read [An easy way to support tags in a jekyll blog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1408824/972240) already, and the only working solution for [github-pages](/questions/tagged/github-pages) was [this one](http://christianspecht.de/tags/), which I don't like, because it puts all tags in one page.

Additionally note that I am using [github-pages](/questions/tagged/github-pages), so custom plugin is not an option.

You can find [full sources here](https://github.com/gevorg/gevorg.github.io).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current Jekyll (3.1.x) cannot generate tag page automatically. You need to use a custom plugin. But you don't want to.

Why ? It's not so difficult to change deployment process on github pages.

You can store you code in `master` and you generated page in `gh-pages`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249255/how-do-i-configure-github-to-use-non-supported-jekyll-site-plugins/28252200#28252200) will give your more information on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, actually I don't mind using custom plugins. I will try that option and if that works then you are my hero.

Comment: It works as expected, semi-automatic build is better then creating tag files manually. Thank You!