# Jekyll tags that have spaces or multiple words

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm using tags in Jekyll for my blog posts. The following is an example of tags I declare in the front matter in the Markdown file:

```
---
tags: [jekyll, tags, user experience]
---
```

The problem I have is that the "user experience" is rendered with a space, which breaks the link for the tag. I'd like to know if it's possible to have tags that have spaces or multiple words.

This is what my code looks like:

**Markup with Ruby:**

```
{% if page.tags.size > 0 %}
  <div class="post-tags">
    <ul>
      {% for tag in page.tags %}
        <li><a href="/tags#{{ tag }}">{{ tag }}</a>{% if forloop.last == false %},{% endif %}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `url_encode` filter : `{{ tag | url_encode }}`.

> Note that url_encode will turn a space into a + sign instead of a percent-encoded character. cf. [Liquid doc](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters#url_encode)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when I [created the tag pages in my blog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002505/6884).

My solution was simply to replace the blanks by dashes:

```
---
tags: [jekyll, tags, user-experience]
---
```

Example front-matter from [one](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/blog/raw/d5363c22755d5e9bc73a27987dff7a76c9bb06b1/src/_posts/2016-01-17-my-home-backup-strategy-part-2-online-services.md) of my posts:

```
tags:
- backup
- bitbucket-backup
- roboshell-backup
- source-control
```

The [finished HTML](https://christianspecht.de/2016/01/17/my-home-backup-strategy-part-2-online-services/) looks like this:

```
<p><small>tags:
    <span class="blog_post_categories">
        <a href="/tags/#backup">backup</a>, 
        <a href="/tags/#bitbucket-backup">bitbucket-backup</a>, 
        <a href="/tags/#roboshell-backup">roboshell-backup</a>, 
        <a href="/tags/#source-control">source-control</a>
    </span>
</small></p>
```

I'm sure that there is a more elegant solution which displays the blanks actually as blanks, but for me, dashes were good enough.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered a fix. When you have spaces in the tags, e.g., "user experience", Jekyll isn't concatenating the words as part of the rendered link, leaving the space between both words: `your.site/tags/user experience`

I needed the two words joined by a `+` because my Tags page rendered a link to that section as `#user+experience`. So I added `replace` like this:

```
{{ tag | replace: " ","+" }}
```

This still feels like a bug in Jekyll, but this process works. Replace the space with whatever syntax you need.