# Jekyll - multiple words in the feature tag: {% for post in site.tags.featured %}

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In the header of Jekyll .md posts I have the following original **featured** tag which I need to amend to **top featured** :

```
layout: post
title:
author:
categories: Jekyll
image:
tags: featured
```

In the Jekyll **sidebar-featured.html** page I have the following html + liquid code:

```
<ol class="list-featured">
    {% for post in site.tags.featured %}   
        <li class="mb-4">
```

If I use **tags: top-featured** and **{% for post in site.tags.top-featured %}** everything works like a charm.

Does Jekyll offer any quick way for using something like **{% for post in site.tags.**<*hardCoded*> **%}** in the liquid code, and mantain the empty space between the two words **top featured** ?

Comment: Hi. You need `assign` to save the hard-coded value as variable. The value can  reused in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use tag-names in array notation (see [Jekyll tags that have spaces or multiple words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40117564/10655742)), change

```yaml
---
layout: post
categories: Jekyll
tags: featured
---
```

to

```yaml
---
layout: post
categories: Jekyll
tags: [ featured ]
---
```

so you can use `spaces` in tags

```yaml
---
layout: post
categories: Jekyll
tags: [ featured, my amazing tag ]
---
```

For **Debugging purpose** you can "log" your tags of the entire site.

```html
## List all Tags of site
<ul>
    {% for tag in site.tags %}
        {% assign t = tag | first %}
        {% assign posts = tag | last %}

        <li>{{ t }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

To list the filterd posts by tag

```html
## One word Tag `featured´
<ol class="list-featured">
    {% for post in site.tags.featured %}
        <li class="mb-4">{{ post.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>

## Two word Tag `top featured´
<ol class="list-featured">
    {% for post in site.tags["top featured"] %}
        <li class="mb-4">{{ post.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Finnally, use assign when you want avoid hard-coded value of your tag

```html
## Two word Tag `top featured´ with **assign**
<ol class="list-featured">
    {% assign myTagName = "top featured" %}
    {% for post in site.tags[myTagName] %}
        <li class="mb-4">{{ post.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Comment: They missing key was ["top featured"] in the liquid code.
Your suggestion worked like a charm